# Print value at a specific id() in Python?

Tags: python, pointers, memory-address

*(The idea is simple but I don't know if it is possible or how to do it in Python)* Like:

```
x = 5
y = id(x)
print(#value_at_y)
```

print should return ***`5`***, which is the value at address y i.e. id(x)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257350/how-to-access-variable-by-id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get a python object from its memory address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748980/can-i-get-a-python-object-from-its-memory-address)

Answer (score 1):

You must use a dictionary. See below:

```
y={}
```

for each x add x and its id(x) to y, like below:

```
y[x]=id(x)
```

And you can call them later with

```
y[x]
```